# I am trying to find out why my value for the radio button is shown on the console but not on the browser when I run the following code?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[n].choices.length; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "radio";
        input.name = "choices";
        input.value = "choice" + i;
        var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
        var option = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[n].choices[i]);
        input.appendChild(option);
        answer.appendChild(input);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slopeofhope81/g9V9d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`input` elements cannot have children](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.text.html):

> The input element is a void element. An input element must have a start tag but must not have an end tag.

[and](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element)

> A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Void elements can have attributes.

You can add the text after the input:

```
var option = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[n].choices[i]);
answer.appendChild(input);
answer.appendChild(option);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/g9V9d/1/)

Comment: "+1" Thank you so much~  I don't know if this is the right way of giving points as an acknowledgement!